# How to detect a remote click in SpriteKit and pass node information

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, tvos

I'm using Swift & SpriteKit.

I've got my sprite focused (using touches began and touches moved) & would like to click the remote to select it, but keep getting:

```
unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Here's the code I'm using..

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "processItemTouch")  
tap.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(integer: UIPressType.Select.rawValue)]  
view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)  

func processItemTouch(nod : SKNode) {
    // stuff to do
}
```

I've tried changing the `processItemTouch` to `processItemTouch: & processItemTouch(nod : SKNode)`.

Comment: Try to add 'Selector' keyword to your action definition like '...action: Selector("processItemTouch")...' And add '@objc' before 'func processItemTouch...'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the selector to `processItemTouch:` should cause the right method to get called, but the argument that gets passed won't be an `SKNode`, it'll be a `UITapGestureRecognizer`. When gestures call their actions, the argument will be the gesture object that triggered the action.

Comment: Hey Justin you sent me in the right direction.  I changed the selector to action: "tapped:" & then set it up...  `func tapped(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        
        self.processItemTouch(focusedNode!)
        
    }`